# How do I use each value of a dataframe column in a loop?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, for-loop

I want to scrape twitter through a series of longitude and latitude values.

I have those values loaded as a dataframe table:

```py
worksheet = gc.open('LA Grid').sheet1

# get_all_values gives a list of rows.
rows = worksheet.get_all_values()
print(rows)

import pandas as pd
pd.DataFrame.from_records(rows)
```

And then I need to run this loop:

```py
total = []
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    tloc = ' 34.052235, -118.243683, 30km'
df_coord = pd.DataFrame(itertools.islice(sntwitter.TwitterSearchScraper(
    'parking lot geocode:"{}"'.format(loc)).get_items(), 50))[['date', 'content']]

df_coord.head()
```

How can I replace the longitude and latitude values for each of the rows in my table?

[image: img]

This is the original code:

```
pip install snscrape
import pandas as pd
import snscrape.modules.twitter as sntwitter
import itertools
loc = '34.052235, -118.243683, 30km'
df_coord = pd.DataFrame(itertools.islice(sntwitter.TwitterSearchScraper(
    'parking lot geocode:"{}"'.format(loc)).get_items(), 50))[['date', 'content']]

df_coord.head()
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverFlow. Please provide us with [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  May I know what you are trying to achieve by using this for-loop ? Are you slicing dataframe?

Comment: Hi! Yes, I'm slicing a twitter search scrape according to coordinates. It works fine if I input each coordinate manually (I'll add it in the post). But I would like to do it from a list of coordinates and not just one value.